# When deleting a file in Nautilus, what's the difference between `del` and `shift+del`?

Tags: nautilus, delete, permanent-delete

In Windows there's a difference between hitting <kbd>Del</kbd> key or <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Del</kbd> keys.

Hitting <kbd>Del</kbd> would simply move the file to recycle bin but hitting  <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Del</kbd> will delete the file permanently.

My question is: Does it work the same way in Nautilus?

Comment: works the same way as in windows

Comment: try it yourself create an empty document and then shift+del it you will see a permenantly delete prompt

Comment: So where's Ubuntu recycle bin? Is that the lost & found folder?

Comment: No. It's `.local/share/Trash`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Works the same way as in windows ,also you can try it yourself

1. Create empty document by right click anywhere on desktop and going to create document option there you will find empty document option
2. after that delete that document with only <kbd>del</kbd> button
3. then recreate a document with same procedure or restore the previous document then 
   <kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>del</kbd> it.

You will see difference yourself(ubuntu recycle bin is trash the last Icon in dash[ubuntu start bar])